# sql performance, visual studio

Tags: sql, performance, visual-studio-2010

I'm using linq2sql and .net 3.5 with vs2010.
I'm experiencing bad sql performance when i run my program through vs2010, but not when i execute the same debug enabled exe outside vs. 
Whats going on here? Any ideas?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If the program is running ok outside visual studio then maybe the sql or linqtosql isn't the problem. If you run it through visual studio with the debugger disabled is the performance better?

Comment: @fsl maybe try disabling the new intellitrace that comes with vs2010 so that you'll have just the classic debugger, I think it will make the difference but will still enable you to debug easily.